# mockedCallback is not called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The following code test fails. In the test, it looks like callback is not called after pressing useEvent.click. Of course, it works correctly in the browser and validations are passed. any help?

Below is the current code for the component, the code for testing and the package information used.

Thank you.

```js
import {
  VStack,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Input,
  FormErrorMessage,
  Textarea,
  Button,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import { CreateRoomForm, createRoomSchema } from "@/lib/yup";
import { useCreateRoom } from "@/hooks/useCreateRoom";

const CreateRoomForm = ({ callback }: { callback: () => void }) => {
  const { isLoading, createRoom } = useCreateRoom();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<CreateRoomForm>({
    resolver: yupResolver(createRoomSchema),
  });

  const handleOnCreate: SubmitHandler<CreateRoomForm> = async (data) => {
    await createRoom(data);
    callback();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnCreate)}>
      <VStack height="full" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.title} isRequired>
          <FormLabel htmlFor="title">タイトル</FormLabel>
          <Input
            id="title"
            placeholder="タイトル"
            type="text"
            {...register("title")}
          />
          <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors.title && errors.title.message}
          </FormErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.capacity} isRequired>
          <FormLabel htmlFor="capacity">参加可能人数</FormLabel>
          <Input
            id="capacity"
            placeholder="4"
            type="number"
            {...register("capacity")}
          />
          <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors.capacity && errors.capacity.message}
          </FormErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.image} isRequired>
          <FormLabel htmlFor="capacity">イメージ</FormLabel>
          <Input
            id="image"
            type="file"
            {...register("image")}
            data-testid="image"
          />
          <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors.image && errors.image.message}
          </FormErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors.description} isRequired>
          <FormLabel htmlFor="description">ルーム詳細</FormLabel>
          <Textarea
            id="description"
            placeholder="ルーム詳細"
            {...register("description")}
          />
          <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors.description && errors.description.message}
          </FormErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>

        <Button
          colorScheme="blue"
          mr={3}
          type="submit"
          alignSelf="flex-end"
          data-testid="submit"
          isLoading={isLoading}
        >
          作成
        </Button>
      </VStack>
    </form>
  );
};

export { CreateRoomForm };
```

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { CreateRoomForm } from "./CreateRoomForm";
import { useCreateRoom } from "@/hooks/useCreateRoom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

jest.mock("../../../hooks/useCreateRoom");
const mockedUseCreateRoom = useCreateRoom as jest.MockedFunction<
  typeof useCreateRoom
>;

const dummyFile = new File([""], "sample.png", { type: "image/png" });
describe("Form", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("calls callback on validation passed", async () => {
    const mockedCallback = jest.fn();
    const mockedCreateRoom = jest.fn(async () => {
      // Simulate async operation and call the callback
      await Promise.resolve();
    });

    mockedUseCreateRoom.mockReturnValue({
      isLoading: false,
      createRoom: mockedCreateRoom,
    });

    render(<CreateRoomForm callback={mockedCallback} />);

    const title = screen.getByPlaceholderText("タイトル");
    const description = screen.getByPlaceholderText("ルーム詳細");
    const capacity = screen.getByPlaceholderText("4");
    const image = screen.getByTestId("image");

    await waitFor(async () => {
      await userEvent.type(title, "title");
      await userEvent.type(description, "description");
      await userEvent.type(capacity, "2");
      await userEvent.upload(image, dummyFile);
    });

    const button = screen.getByTestId("submit");
    await userEvent.click(button);

    await waitFor(() => expect(mockedCallback).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });
});
```

```json
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0"
```

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    Expected number of calls: >= 1                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Received number of calls:    0
```